# Why isn't there a "jekyll post" command to create posts like in hexo?

Tags: jekyll

Do I have to manually create markdown files? Can't jekyll generate a post/draft file with YAML parameters included and YYYY-MM-DD-title filename format?

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [jekyll-compose](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-compose).

It's a command line utility to help you with your workflow. Install it with:

```
gem 'jekyll-compose', group: [:jekyll_plugins]
bundle
```

Then you create pages, blogs etc like this:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll post "My New Post"
```

Please see the link above for full reference.